# htaccess-based redirection of numeric-only URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Let me explain by example — I want the web server to redirect a URL like `http://example.com/-NUM` to `http://example.com/?p=NUM` i.e. for instance, `http://example.com/-121` should be redirected to `http://example.com/?p=121`.

In this case, what should the .htaccess redirection rules look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `^-(\d+)$` will match numeric URI's beginning with a hyphen and capture into `$1`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^-(\d+)$ /?p=$1 [L]
```

If this is a PHP script, for example, you may need to use `index.php` as the target:

```
RewriteRule ^-(\d+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```